# Implement an interface with class wide operations in Ada 95

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class, ada, ada95

I'm creating a program with **Ada 95** and I have a problem. Specifically, I'm trying to implement a class which executes functors given as parameters.

The behavior I want to achieve is:

- Declare an interface `IF` with a procedure `Execute`.
- Derive from `IF` with a class `C` and implement `Execute`.
- Create a class `D` which has a field that is an array of `IF`. Since `IF` cannot be instantiated, I use an array of `access IF`.
- Instantiate an object of class `D` giving it several instances of `C` as parameters.
- Call `Execute` on every instance of `C` contained in the array of `D`.

I've been able to implement the above and compile it, but when I execute it I obtain the error accessibility check failed when trying to assign an object of class `C` to a component of the array in `D`.

I know that the error I obtain is because the assignment I'm doing can lead to a danging pointer error according to the Ada policies, so my question is **what is the proper way to implement this in Ada 95**?

The source code is below. The error is raised in the file `elevators.adb`, in the procedure `Add_Event_Handler`, I have commented the statement that causes it.

## Functors.ads

```ada
package Functors is

    type IFunctor is abstract tagged null record;

    procedure Execute(Self : in out IFunctor) is abstract;

end Functors;
```

## Elevators.ads

```ada
with Functors; use Functors;

package Elevators is

    NOT_A_FLOOR : constant := -1;
    MAX_EVENT_HANDLERS : constant := 255;

    type Floor is new Integer range NOT_A_FLOOR .. 4; 

    type Elevator is private;

    subtype Event_Handler is IFunctor'Class; --'
    type Event_Handler_Index is new Integer range 0 .. MAX_EVENT_HANDLERS;
    type Event_Handers is array(Event_Handler_Index) of access Event_Handler;


    function Create_Elevator return Elevator;

    procedure Add_Stop_Handler(Self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler);
    procedure Add_Moving_Handler(Self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler);
    procedure Add_Called_Handler(Self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler);
    procedure Add_Button_Pressed_Handler(Self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler);

    procedure Run_Simulation(Self : in out Elevator);

    private
        type Elevator is
        record
            Current_Floor : Floor := 0;
            Is_Moving : Boolean := False;
            Next_Floor : Floor := NOT_A_FLOOR;

            Stop : Event_Handers := (others => null);
            Moving : Event_Handers := (others => null);
            Called : Event_Handers := (others => null);
            Button_Pressed : Event_Handers := (others => null);
        end record;

        procedure On_Stop(Self : in out Elevator);
        procedure On_Moving(Self : in out Elevator);
        procedure On_Called(Self : in out Elevator);
        procedure On_Button_Pressed(Self : in out Elevator);

        procedure Add_Event_Handler(Self : out Event_Handers; Handler : access Event_Handler);
        procedure Exec_All_Events(Self : in out Elevator; EH : in Event_Handers);

end Elevators;
```

## Elevators.adb

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Elevators is

    function Create_Elevator return Elevator is
        elev : Elevator;
    begin
        return elev;
    end;

    procedure Add_Stop_Handler(self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
    begin
        Add_Event_Handler(self.Stop, Handler);
    end;

    procedure Add_Moving_Handler(self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
    begin
        Add_Event_Handler(self.Moving, Handler);
    end;

    procedure Add_Called_Handler(self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
    begin
        Add_Event_Handler(self.Called, Handler);
    end;

    procedure Add_Button_Pressed_Handler(self : in out Elevator; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
    begin
        Add_Event_Handler(self.Button_Pressed, Handler);
    end;

    procedure Run_Simulation(self : in out Elevator) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Floor: " & Floor'Image(self.Current_Floor)); --'
        self.Next_Floor := 3;

        On_Called(self);
        On_Moving(self);
        On_Stop(self);
    end;

    procedure On_Stop(self : in out Elevator) is
    begin
        self.Current_Floor := self.Next_Floor;
        self.Is_Moving := False;
        self.Next_Floor := NOT_A_FLOOR;

        Put_Line("Stopped. Current floor = " & Floor'Image(self.Current_Floor)); --'

        Exec_All_Events(self, self.Stop);
    end;

    procedure On_Moving(self : in out Elevator) is
    begin
        self.Is_Moving := True;
        self.Current_Floor := NOT_A_FLOOR;
        Put_Line("Moving to floor " & Floor'Image(self.Next_Floor)); --'

        Exec_All_Events(self, self.Moving);
    end;

    procedure On_Called(self : in out Elevator) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Calling button pressed (" & Floor'Image(self.Next_Floor) & ")..."); --'

        Exec_All_Events(self, self.Moving);
    end;

    procedure On_Button_Pressed(self : in out Elevator) is
    begin
        null;
    end;

    procedure Add_Event_Handler(Self : out Event_Handers; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
        I : Event_Handler_Index := Event_Handler_Index'First; --'
    begin
        while I < Event_Handler_Index'Last loop --'
            if Self(I) = null then
                Self(I) := Handler; -- ======> The error is raised here <======
                exit;
            end if;
            I := I + 1;
        end loop;
    end;

    procedure Exec_All_Events(self : in out Elevator; EH : in Event_Handers) is
        I : Event_Handler_Index := Event_Handler_Index'First; --'
    begin
         while I < Event_Handler_Index'Last loop --'
            if EH(I) /= null then
                EH(I).Execute;
            end if;
            I := I + 1;
        end loop;
    end;

end Elevators;
```

## main.adb

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Functors; use Functors;
with Elevators; use Elevators;

procedure Main is

    type My_Functor is new IFunctor with
    record
        I : Integer := 0;
    end record;

    overriding
    procedure Execute(Self : in out My_Functor) is
    begin
        Put_Line("Executing functor, I is " & Integer'Image(Self.I)); --'
        Self.I := Self.I + 1;
    end;

    Generic_Functor : aliased My_Functor;
    Elev : Elevator := Create_Elevator;
begin
    Add_Stop_Handler(elev, Generic_Functor'Access); --'
    Add_Moving_Handler(elev, Generic_Functor'Access); --'
    Add_Called_Handler(elev, Generic_Functor'Access); --'

    Run_Simulation(Elev);
end;
```

## EDIT

I have done the following changes in order to fix the mentioned runtime error, but I still obtain the `accessibility check failed`.

## elevators.ads

```
...
type Event_Handler_Generic_Ptr is access all Event_Handler;
type Event_Handers is array(Event_Handler_Index) of Event_Handler_Generic_Ptr;
...
```

## elevators.adb

```
procedure Add_Event_Handler(Self : out Event_Handers; Handler : access Event_Handler) is
        I : Event_Handler_Index := Event_Handler_Index'First; --'
    begin
        while I < Event_Handler_Index'Last loop --'
            if Self(I) = null then
                -- Notice the casting here
                Self(I) := Event_Handler_Generic_Ptr(Handler); -- ======> The error is raised here <======
                exit;
            end if;
            I := I + 1;
        end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: I think part of your problem is having your objects (`Elev`, `Generic_Functor`) declared in a procedure. Have you tried declaring them in a package (i.e., at library level)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you store a pointer generated with `'Access` in `Event_Handlers`, you must declare it with **`access all`**, so that it is a *general access type*:

```
type Event_Handers is array(Event_Handler_Index) of access all Event_Handler;
```

If you miss **`all`**, it is a *pool-specific* access type. See [Ada 95 RM, 3.10 Access Types](http://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-03-10.html), (8) and (10). *pool-specific* access types may only hold pointers to objects allocated in a storage pool, which your object is not.

Comment: I have tried it (explained in the edit section) and I obtain the same error.

Comment: I think you also need to change `Handler : access Event_Handler` to `Handler: Event_Handler_Generic_Ptr` in the subprogram signatures, but I'm not sure.